# Creating a javascript function with for loops that returns the number (amount) of even numbers not the actual even numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

> Write a function definition that takes in sequence of numbers and returns the number of even numbers

I've tried creating a `for` loop that counts the all even numbers

```
function countEvens(x){
  var allEven = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    if(x[i] % 2 === 0){
      allEven += x.length;
    }
  }
  return allEven;
}
```

I'm expecting to only get the number of even numbers so if it 1,2,3,4,5 it should return 2.

Comment: The error is in this statement: `allEven += x.length`. Please explain what you think it is doing, and also why `allEven` is declared as an array if you are to return a single number.

Comment: @mustaccio you cant see the part, where its being tested, but the "answer" has an array of numbers and its just going to check that array for the even numbers. And so I have to write a function to check it. Im honestly not sure why i put the " allEven += x.length. im starting to consider leaving that out.

Answer (score 3):

When you're defining `allEven`:

```
var allEven = [];
```

...you're initializing it as an *Array*. That means this line, when it first runs:

```
allEven += x.length;
```

...is the same as:

```
allEven = [] + 5
```

JavaScript is "helpful" enough to do something with this. It decides to convert `[]` to a string `""`, then convert `5` to a string, giving you `"5"` as the result.

You'll want to rethink this approach. This function's job is to *count*, and just like with human counting, that means you want to start at 0:

```
var allEven = 0
```

...and then when you encounter an even, add one to your running count:

```
allEven += 1
```

That should give you your count.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the count, try using a counter and increment that in your loop.

```
function countEvens(x){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    if(x[i] % 2 === 0){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i didnt think to add the 0 for my variable and also using count++